# how to rotate 90 deg text in PDFMake v0.2.7? I am using it an Angular project

Tags: angular, pdfmake

```
 content: [
            {
              text: "This text is rotated by 90 degrees",
              rotation: "90", // specify the rotation angle in degrees
             },
           ],
```

I try this but not worked

i try to rotate a text to `90deg`